# React simply passing props to parent in class componenets

Tags: reactjs

G'day!

Suppose I have a parent component:

```
class Parent extends Component {

//i would need foo to accessible here and for it to update whenever it's changed in the child component.    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and a child one:

```
class Child extends Component {

  state = {
    foo: "",
  };

  handlechange(e) {
    this.setState({foo: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.foo} onChange={this.handlechange}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

how would I pass foo simply and easily from the child to its parent component? I saw some question already relating to this, but I feel as if they are for more complicated purposes than my simple need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: you don't. When you need to do this simply and easily, the state should live in the parent component.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    foo: "",
  };

  handleFooChange = (foo) => {
    this.setState({ foo });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          foo={this.state.foo}
          handleFooChange={this.handleFooChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.props.handleFooChange(event.target.value);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.props.foo}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ahhh, so that is what I'm not getting, thank you very much, react is boggling and confusing, kinda new to me.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

pass a  callback function in child component which can be accesed in parent

Comment: This is essentially the TLDR version of the answer from AKX.. :/